# Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have developed a chat system using javascript and php but the problem is that when a new message is received or the messages are more and more and it got a scroll when new message is receive the user have to scroll custom to go to the bottom so I tried to add the javascript to make the scroll be at bottom but the thing is that it is not working and also getting a javascript error though

here is the error what i got

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined

also I have placed an ajax cache false to refresh chat log every 2 seconds so that the new message can be seen not by refreshing the page by directly refreshing via jquery does it effect this?

here is my code

```
<div class="sidebar-content">
<?php 
    $get_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid != '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");
    while($data_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_query)) {
?>
<div class="contact" onclick="get(<?php echo $data_user["uid"]; ?>);">
    <?php if(!empty($data_user["profile_picture"])) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $data_user["profile_picture"]; ?>" class="contact__photo" />
    <?php } else { ?>
    <img src="uploads/profile_img.jpg" class="contact__photo" />
    <?php } ?>
    <span class="contact__name"><?php echo $data_user["fullname"]; ?></span>
     <span class="chat__id"><?php echo $data_user["uid"]; ?></span>
    <span class="contact__status <?php if($data_user["online_status"] == "Online") { echo "online";} ?>"></span>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="search">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/elastic-srch.png" alt="" class="search__img" />
    <input type="text" class="search__input" placeholder="Search" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="chat">
   <span class="<?php if($status == "Online") { echo 'online_stat';} else {echo "ofline_stat";} ?>"></span>
<span class="chat__back" onclick="reload();"></span>
<span class="chat__status">status</span>
<div class="chat__person">
  <span class="chat__online active"></span>
  <span class="chat__name" id="chat_name">Huehue Huehue</span>
   <span class="contact__id" id="contact__id">Huehue Huehue</span>
</div>
<div id="chat_messages">
</div>
<script>

    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    var timeout = setInterval(reloadChat, 2000);    
    function reloadChat () {
        var rid = document.getElementById("contact__id").innerHTML;
         $('#msgs').load('includes/messages.php?receipt_id='+rid);
    }
    $('#chat-scroll').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#msgs').get(0).scrollHeight}, 2000);   
</script>

 </div>
```

Comment: There is no element with id `chat-scroll` in your html, `$('#chat-scroll')` returns `undefined`.

Comment: updated my code check now please

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: I figured out the error okay so now the div id #msgs is in this file messages.php and script is in chat.php does it will effect ?

Comment: The scroll at bottom is working but this refresh function is not allowing to user to croll up and see older messages any suggestion to prevent this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
scrollTop: $('#msgs').get(0).scrollHeight}, 2000);
```

to

```
scrollTop: $('#msgs').eq(0).scrollHeight}, 2000);
```

or

```
scrollTop: $('#msgs')[0].scrollHeight}, 2000);
```